# How to define window or document in Angular2/JQuery WebApp?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

The purpose of doing all of the following is: The main-menu of my WebApp should close on click (if its a small device for example SmartPhone, Tablet) and stay open (if its a large device for example PC Monitor).

Part of the nav.component.html:

```
<li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']"*ngIf="!userService.HideOnClick()">
   <a [routerLink]="['/version']">
      <span class='fa fa-info'></span> Informationen Large Device
   </a>
</li>

<li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']"*ngIf="userService.HideOnClick()">
   <a [routerLink]="['/version']">
      <span class='fa fa-info'></span> Informationen Small Device
   </a>
</li>
```

Part of the user.service.ts (which contains the functions of the menu since you can only see parts of the menu without beeing a user (you can see the example without beeing logged in)):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'angular-2-local-storage';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

   constructor(private _http: Http, private _localStorage: LocalStorageService) {
      //Only interesting for login
   }

   HideOnClick(): boolean {
       var w = window.innerWidth;
       //document.body.clientWidth;
       console.log(w);
       if (w < 766) return true;
       else return false;
   };
}
```

Running it I get the following message: (same with document...)

```
Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Sure I do not have defined "window", but since VS is not telling me that something is wrong and I can go to its implementation (with right click)...

How can I define/import window?

or

How can I get the window size in this methode?

or

Where would I normaly place such a methode?

Thank you for your help!
If you need more information please ask!

Comment: You don't want to use UI / DOM Api inside your services, this beats the whole idea of having Angular2 and MVVM in the first place. It's there to separate UI Logic from your business logic

Comment: So where do i want to have it?

Comment: Since I have not started the project on my own i am still struggling to figure out where things have to go to

Comment: Did you tried using (twitter) bootstrap, which was designed responsive design which works on Desktop and Mobile? http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: I have bootstrap installed via npm as far as i know... how does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Foreword

You shouldn't access DOM from your components or services, because this beats the purpose of having DI and MVVM pattern for separation of view and business & presentation logic. It also makes it hard to unit test your logic w/o a browser.

Like mentioning it in the comments, to control the width or visibility of a view you should use bootstrap (or similar responsive framework), which offer this kind of functionality and directly embed this into your view.

Your services and presentation logic (inside your Components) should not be aware of this, as it's a pure view concern.

Bootstrap supports the mobile click to open a menu (which seems to be what you are looking for based on the code example).

Look at the http://getbootstrap.com webpage. When you make your browser window width very small, it turns the menu into a hamburger menu.

See the "Default Navbar" example on Bootstrap [examples](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) (shorted a bit for brevity).

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        ...
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            ...
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      ...
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

The important thing here is, that you have two different html markups for representing mobile/desktop views, which switch depending on the available size.

You can also use the [visible/hidden classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) to hide an element at a certain size, i.e.

```
<li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']" class="visible-md-inline visible-lg-inline">
   <a [routerLink]="['/version']">
      <span class='fa fa-info'></span> Informationen Large Device
   </a>
</li>

<li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']" class="visible-xs-inline visible-sm-inline">
   <a [routerLink]="['/version']">
      <span class='fa fa-info'></span> Informationen Small Device
   </a>
</li>
```

This will make the first one visible when smaller than 992px; xs (extra-small) classes are for width < 768 px, sm (small) for <=992 px, md (>=992px) and lg (>=1200px).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I havent tested it jet, but I will tomorow!